# How to update jsonb column data of postgress using data-jpa?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

how to update jsonb postgresql table column using jpa?

when I tried definition for column entity as jsonb it throw error

Comment: please share more details and the error you are facing .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in may case I've annotated the field corresponding to the jsonb column in this way

```
@Convert(converter = JpaConverters.JsonConverter.class)
@ColumnTransformer(
        write = "?::jsonb"
)
public ObjectNode caratteristiche;
```

where JsonConvert is a custom converter

```
public class JpaConverters {
    @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public static class JsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<JsonNode, String> {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(JsonNode entityValue) {
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(entityValue);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public JsonNode convertToEntityAttribute(String databaseValue) {
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                return mapper.readValue(databaseValue, ObjectNode.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException ex){
                return null;
            }
        }


        public static JsonNode toJson(String str){
            var myself =  new JsonConverter();
            return myself.convertToEntityAttribute(str);
        }

    }
}
```

the convert allow to map the jsonb type as a Java JsonNode from jackson. Hope that this can help